# PHP:List of files in a directory

Tags: php, html-lists, scandir

I'm learning HTML, CSS, and PHP.

I' currently trying to write a script which lists all files inside a folder
as an ordered list of download links.

Script works well, but after every list item with link it puts an extra
empty item like this:

```
<ol>
    <li><a href="/~ftp/files/file1.txt">file1.txt</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a href="/~ftp/files/file2.txt">file2.txt</a></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
```

I cannot figure out why.
Here is the page code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Files</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #D8DBE2;
        }
        div {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px 5px;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: white;
            border-style: none;
            border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
        }
        ol {
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: white;
            border-style: none;
            border-radius: 0px 6px 6px 6px;
            width: 500px;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p><b>Files</b></p>
    </div>
    <ol>
        <?php
        $dir = '/home/ftp/public_html/files';
        $files = array_slice(scandir($dir),2); //getting rid of "." and ".."
        $s = sizeof($files);
        for ($i=0;$i<$s;$i++)
        {
            $file=implode("",array_slice($files,$i,1));
            echo "<li><a href=\"/~ftp/files/".$file."\">".$file."</a><li>";
        }
        ?>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Missing `/` in `</li>`. Since `</li>` is optional, the browser assumes you actually have a new, empty, list item.

Comment: Oh... Thank you very much! Seems that I'm blind =))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're not closing the `<li>` tag, but opening a new one in each iteration. HTML is not that smart, so you need to do things correctly.

Try changing this: `"<li><a href=\"/~ftp/files/".$file."\">".$file."</a><li>"`

To this: `"<li><a href=\"/~ftp/files/".$file."\">".$file."</a></li>"`

Besides this, your code have another problems, and could be write in a simpler way, like this:

```
$dir = '/home/ftp/public_html/files';
$files = array_slice(scandir($dir),2);
foreach($files as $file){
    echo '<li><a href="/~ftp/files/'.$file.'">'.$file."</a></li>";
}
```

You have a problem in your `<doctype>` declaration too, is missing a **!** on the tag. The correct way is like this: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing the HTML li tag properly:

```
echo "<li><a href=\"/~ftp/files/".$file."\">".$file."</a></li>";
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the forward slash in a closing `</li>` tag.

```
echo "<li><a href=\"/~ftp/files/{$file}\">{$file}</a></li>";
```

Comment: Quotes are escaped properly in the OP's code, and you haven't fixed the issue here.

Comment: My bad. Fixed it now.

Comment: Now you just have a line of code, with no explanation of what you changed, why you changed it, and how it fixes the problem.

Comment: Oh, well, live a century - learn a century. Thanks for your feedback. Just wrapping my head around SO.

Comment: Unfortunately there's still a problem: questions where the problem is caused by a typo should be closed, not answered ;) You don't have your close-hammer yet, but when you do that's what it's for.

Comment: Ready to hammer, Sir!